# How to set the position of thumbnail for QDrag in a QFrame?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In my `QFrame` object, I am trying to achieve the effect where on mouse-down and mouse-move, a thumbnail follows the position of the cursor. I managed to achieve this. However, the thumbnail have some sort of an animation where it will 'fly in' from the `0,0` of the `QFrame` object towards the position of where the cursor is and back to `0,0` on mouse-release.

It looks something like that:

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap

class Example(QFrame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        mimeData = QMimeData()
        drag = QDrag(self)
        thumbnail = QPixmap('test.png').scaled(100, 100, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        drag.setPixmap(thumbnail)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos())
        drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

What should be added/changed such that the thumbnail appears directly at the position of the cursor instead of 'flying in' and 'flying out'?

Comment: that effect seems more like Mac OS, in linux I do not observe that behavior, on the other hand it removes `drag.setHotSpot(e.pos())` is not necessary.

Comment: cool! thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap

class Example(QFrame): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.label = QLabel(self)     # +++
        self.label.resize(100, 100)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)     # +++

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        mimeData = QMimeData()
        drag     = QDrag(self)
        self.thumbnail = QPixmap('E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png').scaled(100, 100, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        drag.setPixmap(self.thumbnail)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
#        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos())  
        drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction) 

    def dropEvent(self, e):           # +++
        self.label.setPixmap(self.thumbnail)
        self.label.move(e.pos())

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):      # +++
        if e.mimeData():
            e.acceptProposedAction()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this works! However, I do not want the thumbnail to be dropped in the `QFrame`, so i've removed the `dropEvent` and `dragEnterEvent`. This time, on mouse-release, the thumbnail 'flies' towards the point where i first clicked within the `QFrame`. is it possible that, on mouse-release, the `QLabel` disappears immediately? instead of returning to its 'original' position and then disappearing?